# Javascript confirm box-checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Im interested in how to make a confirm box in Javascript that would be triggered by onchange method on several cboxes.
So i need 2 checkboxes for like ON and OFF values. If someone checks or unchecks one, confirm box will show and if clicked OK, then the state of cbox will change, if not then the value will not be changed. Any ideas?

Thank you.

So far i tried this:

```
<label> On </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="output2Radio"  id="output2Radio1" onchange="conf(this);">
<label> Off </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="output2Radio"  id="output2Radio1" onchange="conf(this);">


<script type="text/javascript">
    function conf(box) {
    if (!box.checked) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?"))
    {box.checked = true;}}}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to write code for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confirm Save during onchange of drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130707/confirm-save-during-onchange-of-drop-down)

Comment: Please attach code you have tried.

Comment: example of code i tried so far only makes changes if box is checked. how can i make it do do both ways?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code, its working

[plnkr.co/edit/kQW3KDJMbXOPrJinbgB4?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/kQW3KDJMbXOPrJinbgB4?p=preview)

HTML

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cbox" id="cbox" onchange="onCbChange('cbox')"></input>
</body>
```

Javascript :

```
function onCbChange(cb) {
    var b = document.getElementById(cb).checked;

    var confirmBox = confirm("Change?");

    if (confirmBox == true) {
        if (b) {
            document.getElementById(cb).checked = true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(cb).checked = false;
        }
    } else {
        
        document.getElementById(cb).checked = !b;
    };
}
```